# C# DataTable - GroupBy then OrderBy

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I have a DataTable that contains 5 columns.

Activity (string)
Clock In (DateTime)
Clock Out (DateTime)
Total (double)
Type (int)

I am needing to GroupBy the Clock Out DateTime.Date and within that OrderBy the Type.

So essentially, if I have data, I want it grouped/order like this:

```
Activity    Clock In           Clock Out          Total    Type

Drawing     09/16/13 13:30     09/16/13 13:32     0.02     1
Drawing     09/16/13 13:40     09/16/13 13:42     0.02     1
Testing     09/16/13 13:50     09/16/13 13:52     0.02     1
Testing     09/16/13 13:30     09/16/13 13:34     0.04     2
Testing     09/16/13 13:40     09/16/13 13:54     0.14     2


Drawing     09/17/13 13:50     09/17/13 13:52     0.02     1
Testing     09/17/13 13:30     09/17/13 13:34     0.04     2
Testing     09/17/13 13:40     09/17/13 13:54     0.14     2


Testing     09/18/13 13:52     09/18/13 13:54     0.02     2
```

I have all the data in a DataTable already, I just need help with the grouping...

Any thoughts??  I have tried:

```
groupedSortedTbl = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(d => d.Field<DateTime>("CLOCK_OUT").Date)
                    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(t => t.Field<int>("Type")))
                    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Do you want to group by `Clock Out`? If so, why do you use `SelectMany` to flatten out them afterwards at all? You could use `OrderBy`+`ThenBy` instead.

Comment: `SelectMany` is effectively getting rid of the grouping.  Do you want a single result set or a collection of groups?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do this...

```
groupedSortedTbl = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .OrderBy(d => d.Field<DateTime>("CLOCK_OUT").Date)
                    .ThenBy(t => t.Field<int>("Type"))
                    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to group by `Clock Out`? If so, why do you use `SelectMany` to flatten them out  afterwards at all? You could use `OrderBy` + `ThenBy` instead.

```
DataTable groupedSortedTbl = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(row => row.Field<DateTime>("CLOCK_OUT").Date)
    .ThenBy(row  => row.Field<int>("Type"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you want to keep the groups, you cannot use `CopyToDataTable` at the end to create the `DataTable`. So you could create an `IEnumerable<Anonymous/Custom Type>` instead. Or you could select many `DataTables`, one for every date-group:

```
IEnumerable<DataTable> dateGroups = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<DateTime>("CLOCK_OUT").Date)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(t => t.Field<int>("Type")).CopyToDataTable());
```